# Matlab - PSD with same length as the signal?

Tags: matlab

I have an audiosignal(130k sample values) and want to create its PSD with the same amount of samples. (Has to do something with adaptive Pre/De-emphasis)

So my question is: Is this possible and if yes, how?

I tried serveral ways but all failed.. 
First try (use autocorrelation of the signal and afterwards the fouriertransform, which is the only way I'm sure it should work theoretically):

```
[y,fs]=audioread('test.wav');
N=length(y);
r=xcorr(y);
fft(r,length(y))
```

Another way would be using:

```
[pyy,f]=pwelch(y,[],[],[],fs)
```

but in this case the length of pyy is not the right one.
And lastly I found this:

```
    N=length(y);
    bin_vals=0:N-1;
    fax_Hz= bin_vals*fs/N;
    N_2=ceil(N/2);
    pyy=fft(y).*conj(fft(y));
```

But if I understand the code right it gives me the power spectrum of y and not the power spectral density.

I'm getting very frustrated with this and am grateful for any kind of help!

Comment: Klaus, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The frequency resolution of the psd depends on the window size. The easiest way to get a proper psd estimate and maximize the window length is

```
[pyy,f]=pwelch(y,length(y),[],[],fs)
```

In this case you will get a psd that is half as long as your signal. This is the maximum, because (assuming your signal is real-valued), negative frequency content is identical to positive frequency content, meaning the full psd from -fs/2 to +fs/2 is mirror symmetric, and so it makes no sense to use the negative part.

However, I don't think this estimate is very useful. psd estimates are roughly distributed as a scaled chi-squared random variable with 2d degrees of freedom, where d is the number of windowed single estimates the estimate was averaged over. For maximal resolution, 1 windowed estimate, it is therefore a scaled chi-squared random variable with two degrees of freedom. For such a random variable, the error of the estimate is of the same size as the estimate itself, meaning such a psd estimate is basically useless.